# Is it possible to change the loadui for a subgrid in jqGrid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid, jquery-blockui

I have a jqGrid (4.1.1) using a simple subgrid. When a record is plus-ed out to view the subgrid, a loadui different from my normal one pops up.

My current configuration is to use `loadui: none`, and on the `beforeRequest` event I show my own loader.

If I use my custom one on the `subGridBeforeExpand` event, it shows my message as well as the default message. I also don't see where I would hide my div when loading is complete. `subGridRowExpanded` doesn't seem to be the right place.

In short:

1. Is there a jqGrid setting to hide the subgrid loadui, or do I have to roll my own javascript to hide it?
2. Which events can I hook into to make sure the subgrid is loaded so I can close my loader?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look in the code of the subgrid you could find [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.1.2/js/grid.subgrid.js#L147) the place where the the loading div will be displayed just as

```
$("#load_"+ts.p.id).show();
```

on the other side the code to show the standard (main) grid looks as the following (see here):

```
beginReq = function() {
    ts.grid.hDiv.loading = true;
    if(ts.p.hiddengrid) { return;}
    switch(ts.p.loadui) {
        case "disable":
            break;
        case "enable":
            $("#load_"+$.jgrid.jqID(ts.p.id)).show();
            break;
        case "block":
            $("#lui_"+$.jgrid.jqID(ts.p.id)).show();
            $("#load_"+$.jgrid.jqID(ts.p.id)).show();
            break;
    }
}
```

So you can see that the setting `loadui: "disable"` will be used *only in the main grid*. How you can see from the code above any value of `loadui` other as `"enable"` or `"block"` (like unknown "none" value which you use) will be interpret as the `loadui: "disable"`.

In my view **it is a bug in the subgrid**.

As the workaround I suggest you just *remove the loading div after creating of jqGrid*. If the table element of your grid has `id="list"` for example, then the next line:

```
$("div#load_list").remove();
```

will just delete the div and you will never see it in both main grid and subgrid.

**UPDATED** based on the comments: OK! Now I understand your problem. I though before that you used `datatype: 'local'`. In case of the usage some remote datatype and [blockUI](https://github.com/malsup/blockui) plugin you can do the following. The `ajax` call used by jqGrid for the subgrid currently you can see [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.1.2/js/grid.subgrid.js#L157). It uses `complete` event, so the `success` and `error` events of the [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) are free now. So you can use the events to call `.unblock()` or `$.unblockUI()` methods which will close the loading overlay. You can use [ajaxSubgridOptions](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3asubgrid&s%5B%5D=ajaxsubgridoptions#properties) parameter of the jqGrid

```
$("#list").jqGrid({
    // options of grid of subgrid ...
    ajaxSubgridOptions {
        success: function () {
            $.unblockUI(); // or $("#list").unblock();
        },
        error: function () {
            $.unblockUI(); // or $("#list").unblock();
        }
    }
);
```

If it's not solve your problem you should include in your question the code fragment which explains how you use [blockUI](https://github.com/malsup/blockui) plugin and I will modify the code by inserting the calls of unblocking methods.

Comment: I agree that this would be considered a bug. Your solution works like a charm. Do you have any thoughts on how to hide my loader when the subgrid is done loading?

Comment: @IronicMuffin: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Which "loader" you want to hide? If you remove the loader div no loader should be displayed. Could you explain more exactly the situation which you have. Which `subgridtype` for example you use?

Comment: I am using the blockui plugin to display my own overlay with a loading message. I show this on `subGridBeforeExpand` but there doesn't seem to be a `subGridLoadComplete` event to hook in to where I could then hide my loader.

Comment: @IronicMuffin: I understand now your problem. I wrote "UPDATED" part in my answer.